# Return " i " value when if-statement is true

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I have created a matrix with row 1 full of strings and 4 other rows with numbers. They are created in a handle class with the object "Projekter".

So in the object "Projekter" row 1, the first value is blank, but the second value is 'Ole'. So I know that 'Ole' is in (1,2). x is the name/string I want to search for, which in this case is 'Ole'.

As you see below it should search row 1 from column 2 untill the last name/string and if i = 'Ole', it should bring me the value 2 because " i " should be equal 2.

A is just a controller if the function works, but at this point it doesn't.
The error it gives is "Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'."

How do I fix this so it return the " i " value when the statement is correct?

Thank you in advance!

```
function number(obj,x)

A = [];
for i = 2:size(obj.Projekter,2)
    if obj.Projekter(1,i)==x
        A = A + 1;
    end
end
disp(A)

end
```

Comment: Can you also provide the code where you prepare the data you pass into the function?

Comment: The `find` function is quite good at this.  Probably `find(strcmp(obj.Projeckter(1,:), x))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to index the cell content:

```
your_cell = {'a_string'};
your_string = your_cell{1};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function [returnValue] = number(obj,x)

for i = 2:size(obj.Projekter,2)
    if obj.Projekter{1,i}==x
        returnValue = i;
        return;
    end
end
end
```

Note the change from `obj.Projekter(1,i)==x` to `obj.Projekter{1,i}==x` (use curly braces instead of parens).  I have then specified that `returnValue` will hold the value that should be returned by doing `function [returnValue] = number(obj,x)`.  We then set `returnValue` equal to `i` and return from the function when the condition of the if statement is true.

As suggested in the comments, it is probably better to do:

```
function [returnValue] = number(obj, x)
  returnValue = find(strcmp(x, obj.Projekter) == 1);
```

`strcmp(x, obj.Projektor)` will give you an array the length of `obj.Projekter` with 1's wherever the strings match, and 0's where they don't, you can then `find` the indices that are set to 1.  This has the added benefit of

1. not using a loop so it's faster
2. Giving you every occurrence of a match, not just the first one.

Comment: Even better, use `strcmp`, which won't cause an error if the character arrays have different length.